# Grunt Serve throws maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I made an angular app with the command

```
yo angular
```

after building this project I want to run it with 'grunt serve', which throws following output repetitive:

```
...
(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.
    (node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.
    (node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.

    util.js:35
      var str = String(f).replace(formatRegExp, function(x) {
```

My localhost opens with an error that the page couldn't be loaded.
What is this this problem?

Comment: Did you found out the core of the problem and how to fix it?